# Possible to reference two specifc tables with one query

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

This already involves four INNER JOINs and one LEFT JOIN, but I am not sure how I can reference one more table that is similar to the LEFT JOIN table.

Here is my current query which works as it is suppose to

```
 SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, xiW.id, xiW.image_path, count(xvi.variantid) as cnt
    FROM xcart_products xp
    INNER JOIN xcart_variants xv ON xp.productid = xv.productid
    INNER JOIN xcart_variant_items xvi ON xv.variantid = xvi.variantid
    INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xvi.optionid = xco.optionid
    INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xco.classid = xc.classid AND xc.class = 'COLOR'
    LEFT JOIN xcart_images_W xiW ON xiW.id = xvi.variantid
    GROUP BY xco.optionid
    ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

So essentially each product has both a class and a variant, then each class has class options, and each variant has variant items.  The variants have their own variant image and each class has it's own 'detailed' image (xcart_images_D).  As of now I am referencing the variant images but what I would like to do is instead of counting xvi.variantid I want to count how many detailed images there are for each of optionid.

I have a query which will do this but unfortunately I cannot use this query to pull xcart_images_W.  That query is belo

```
 SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, xiD.image_path, xiD.path_on_server, count(xiD.optionid) as cnt
    FROM xcart_products xp
    INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xp.productid = xc.productid AND xc.class = 'Color'
    INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xc.classid = xco.classid
    LEFT JOIN xcart_images_D xiD ON xiD.optionid = xco.optionid
    GROUP BY xp.product, xco.optionid
    ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

Is it possible to reference these two tables or do their foreign keys make it impossible to do so?

Below I have provided the table structures.

```
+ xcart_products
    - productid*
    - product
+ xcart_variants
    - variantid*
    - productid (xcart_products.productid)
+ xcart_variant_items [bridge table]
    - optionid*
    - variantid (xcart_variants.variantid)
+ xcart_classes
    - classid*
    - productid (xcart_products.productid)
    - class
+ xcart_class_options
    - optionid*
    - option_name
    - classid (xcart_classes.classid)
+ xcart_images_W
    - imageid*
    - id (xcart_variants.variantid)
    - image_path
+ xcart_images_D
    - imageid* [not relational with xcart_images_W.imageid]
    - id (xcart_products.productid)
    - optionid (xcart_class_options.optionid)
    - image_path

* Primary Key
() relational data
[] notes
```

Currently working but messy query.  How do I clean up?

```
 SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, xiW.id, xiW.image_path
 FROM xcart_products xp
 INNER JOIN xcart_variants xv ON xp.productid = xv.productid
 INNER JOIN xcart_variant_items xvi ON xv.variantid = xvi.variantid
 INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xvi.optionid = xco.optionid
 INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xco.classid = xc.classid AND xc.class = 'COLOR'
 LEFT JOIN xcart_images_W xiW ON xiW.id = xvi.variantid
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT COUNT(xiD.optionid) as dCount 
    FROM xcart_products xp2
    INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc2 ON xp2.productid = xc2.productid AND xc2.class = 'Color'
    INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco2 ON xc2.classid = xco2.classid
    LEFT JOIN xcart_images_D xiD ON xiD.optionid = xco2.optionid
 ) ON xiW.id = xvi.variantid
 GROUP BY xco.optionid
 ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear until you provide table definition. Have you tried replacing count(xvi.variantid) with count(xiW.id) in the first query?

updated:

```
SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, xiW.id, xiW.image_path, count(xvi.variantid) as cnt
FROM xcart_products xp
INNER JOIN xcart_variants xv ON xp.productid = xv.productid
INNER JOIN xcart_variant_items xvi ON xv.variantid = xvi.variantid
INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xvi.optionid = xco.optionid
INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xco.classid = xc.classid AND xc.class = 'COLOR'
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT COUNT(xiD.id) as Dcount 
   FROM xcart_images_D xiD 
   INNER JOIN xcart_images_W xiW ON xiW.column = xiD.column /*please update accordingly */
 ) ON xiW.id = xvi.variantid 
GROUP BY xco.optionid
ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

updated again:

```
SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, xiW.id, xiW.image_path, count(xvi.variantid) as cnt, xiD.totalD
FROM xcart_products xp
INNER JOIN xcart_variants xv ON xp.productid = xv.productid
INNER JOIN xcart_variant_items xvi ON xv.variantid = xvi.variantid
INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xvi.optionid = xco.optionid
INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xco.classid = xc.classid AND xc.class = 'COLOR'
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT count(xiD.id) as totalD, xiD.optionid FROM xcart_images_D xiD WHERE xiD.optionid = xvi.optionid
) ON xiD.optionid = xvi.optionid
GROUP BY xco.optionid
ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

Comment: Hi JA Thank you for the assistance.  I will provide a layout of the table, but I had tried your suggestion earlier and the problem is that each xiW has it's own set of images and so does xiD.  When I count xiW it counts the number of variant images and what I am looking for is a count of the detailed images instead of variant images.

Comment: Could you please provide xiW and xiD table definitions. Also, whet happens when you execute the query above (updated my post for readability)?.

Comment: Sure thing JA, I went ahead and added the important information for the referenced tables in my original post.

Comment: Thank you for the updated query.  My issue is that xiD and xIW are not relational with each other.  But I do believe you are on the right track.  I'm going to mess around with the query a bit and I'l let you know if I make any progress.

Comment: ah, didn't realize xiD and xiW weren't linked. Updated my post. Should be closer to desired result.

Comment: Excellent, much cleaner than what I ended up using to get the query to work (which I've added in the original post).

Only problem is I get an error stating "Every derived table must have its own alias", I add an 'AS t1' before 'ON' and then get an error stating "Unknown table 'xvi' in where clause."

So I suppose my question now is how do I use an alias in a derived table that is pulled from the original SELECT?  Also does 'LEFT JOIN xcart_images_W xiW ON xiW.id = xvi.variantid' still need to be right before the derived table?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the silly mistake. It is kinda hard to write queries if there's no actual data to test :( will update the post shortly.

Comment: No worries I definitely thank you for your assistance I realize how difficult it can be writing queries with no test data and with such limited information.  Regardless you've been a huge help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11127/discussion-between-eric-and-j-a)